# IPython startup file produces unexpected results with matplotlib configuration

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, ipython

I have the following code in *~/.ipython/profile_default/startup/00_startup.ipy* file, in which I set up plots theme and size using the [jupyter-themes](https://github.com/dunovank/jupyter-themes) package.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from jupyterthemes import jtplot

jtplot.style(theme='chesterish', figsize=(21, 14), grid=False)
# plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (31, 14)
x = 20
```

When I start a new kernel the theme of the plots is the one I have chosen in the *jtplot.style()* function, but the size is the default one and also there is this weird black border.
[image: plot1]

If I run the same *jtplot* function from within a cell the result is as expected.

[image: plot2]

I have tried going around this by setting the *figsize* parameter in the matplotlib *rcParams*, but again it only works from within a cell and not in the IPython startup file. The *x* variable from the file has the value 20 assigned to it when I start a new kernel, so I know the code executes properly.

The screenshots are from a notebook inside Visual Studio Code, but I have conducted the same experiments in a regular jupyter notebook and the results are consistent among these two environments.

Is there something that might be overwriting the figure size after the startup file was executed, or anything else that might cause this behaviour?

I have a fresh setup with those versions:

- macOS Monterey 12.3 with the M1 Pro
- conda 4.12.0
- python 3.10.5
- ipython 8.4.0
- jupyterthemes 0.20.0

Answer (score 0):

The `%matplotlib inline` command needs to be called in the first line of the startup file. Not sure exactly how this works, but if it is after the matplotlib import it gets called again by some other source, which overwrites matplotlib configuration.

Sometimes I hate programming.